# If $P$ is a complex polynomial function , $P(\mathbb{C})$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, polynomials

*Statement* :

**If P is a complex polynomial function $P : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ , different from the constant polynomial functions ,then $P(\mathbb{C})$ is a closed set(in $\mathbb{C}$).**

*Proof :*

Let $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\in P(\mathbb{C})^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence converging in $\mathbb{C}$ and let's demonstrate the latter sequence converge in $P(\mathbb{C})$.

Let's write $P$ as $P(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{deg(P)}a_k X^k$ , $X\in \mathbb{C}$ .

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , there exists $H_n \in \mathbb{C}$ , such that $h_n=\sum_{k=0}^{deg(P)}a_k H_n^k$.

**Since this point i'm a bit stuck , how can i finish this proof ?**

Note to the reader : I don't have the right to use the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(z_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ a convergent sequence of points of $P(\Bbb C)$ and let $z=\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n$; I will prove that $z\in P(\Bbb C)$. It follows from this that $P(\Bbb C)$ is a closed set.

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, let $w_n\in\Bbb C$ be such that $P(w_n)=z_n$. Since the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, it is bounded. It follows from this that the sequence  $(w_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is also bounded. In fact, if$$P(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_Nz^N$$with $a_N\ne0$, then $|P(z)|\geqslant\frac12\left|a_Nz^N\right|$ if $|z|$ is large enough, and therefore $P$ maps unbounded sequence into unbounded sequences.

Since the sequence  $(w_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded, it has a subsequence $(w_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ which converges to some $w\in\Bbb C$. But then\begin{align}z&=\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(w_n\right)\\&=\lim_{k\to\infty}P(w_{n_k})\\&=P\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}w_{n_k}\right)\\&=P(w)\\&\in P(\Bbb C).\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain the part "$|P(z)|\geqslant\frac12\left|a_Nz^N\right|$ if $|z|$ is large enough " , what is used for this result ?

Comment: You have\begin{align}|P(z)|&\leqslant\left|a_Nz^N\right|-\left|a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_{N-1}z^{N-1}\right|\\&\geqslant\left|a_Nz^N\right|-\left|z^N\right|\left(\frac{|a_0|}{|z|^N}+\frac{|a_1|}{|z|^{N-1}}+\cdots+\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|z|}\right).\end{align}Now, use the fact that$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{|a_0|}{|z|^N}+\frac{|a_1|}{|z|^{N-1}}+\cdots+\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|z|}=0$$and that therefore$$\frac{|a_0|}{|z|^N}+\frac{|a_1|}{|z|^{N-1}}+\cdots+\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|z|}<\frac{|a_N|}2$$if $|z|$ is large enough.

Comment: I think there is a $P$ too much in the third last line.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w \in \mathbb C$ and let $Q(z):=P(z)-w.$ By the Fundamental theorem of algebra, there is some $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ such that $Q(z_0)=0,$ hence $w =P(z_0) \in P( \mathbb C).$ This gives $P(\mathbb C)= \mathbb C.$

Comment: I should have precized it so i'm adding it to my post , but **i don't have the right using the fundamental theorem of algebra**

Comment: That's why we ask answerers to seek clarification from an asker, so they can better understand the level at which to address a question.  Neither answerer to you question bothered to first ask for more context, before jumping in to answer.